How to get the Table row number instead of the worksheet row number
I just asked a question about getting the column number for a known column name and the answer to that was .index
I am trying to return the last used row for an entire named table.  If I used the .end(xlup) method based on the worksheet it will always stop at the edge of the table regardless if the bottom cell of the table is empty or not.  Instead I changed it up to the following:
My Code:
Function TableLastUsedRow(TheTable As ListObject) As Long

Dim RowCount As Long, ColCount As Long, TableLastRow As Long

    With TheTable
        TableLastRow = .ListRows.count
    
        For ColCount = 1 To .ListColumns.count
            If IsEmpty(.DataBodyRange.Cells(TableLastRow, ColCount)) Then
                RowCount = .DataBodyRange.Cells(TableLastRow, ColCount).End(xlUp).Row
                If TableLastUsedRow < RowCount Then TableLastUsedRow = RowCount
            Else
                TableLastUsedRow = TableLastRow
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next ColCount
    End With

End Function

This works great in returning the worksheet row reference.  How do you get the row number of the table?
Updated Code Line
RowCount = .DataBodyRange.Cells(TableLastRow, ColCount).End(xlUp).ListRow.Index

This is generating the following error:


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrow.index

@TimWilliams hrrmmm.  i did try changing the .row to .index and that gave me an error.  I forgot to mention that.  I will take a read of this and see what it says.  I tried replacing .row with .listrow.index and that was a no go

Index of the Last Non-Blank (Data) Row of an Excel Table
Function TableLastUsedRow(ByVal TheTable As ListObject) As Long
    With TheTable
        Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = .ListRows.Count
        ' The following line will exit the function and return 0.
        ' It might be better to return -1. You know how.
        If RowsCount = 0 Then Exit Function ' empty table
        With .DataBodyRange
            Dim lcell As Range:
            Set lcell = .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If lcell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' all cells are blank
            ' Number of Populated (Data) Rows =
            '     Last Worksheet Row - First Worksheet Row + 1
            TableLastUsedRow = lcell.Row - .Row + 1
        End With
    End With
End Function


Does the : mean end of line / start new line?

It means that the variable is initialized in the following line. The declaration and initialization don't fit in a single line (I like my lines <=80 chars). If you hate it, remove it.

Never used the : before as my style tends to be Dim at the start, not where you call it.  Though I can see some merits of both methods.  I had to step through the code before I finally understood the 'Number of Populated (Data) Rows = Last Worksheet Row - First Worksheet Row + 1  comment, but now I get it.  This seems much quicker and cleaner than what I was trying.

Different approach - just loop backwards over the rows
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print LastUsedRowIndex(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1))
End Sub


'Return the index of the last row in the table `TheTable`
' return zero if table is empty
Function LastUsedRowIndex(TheTable As ListObject) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = TheTable.ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(TheTable.ListRows(i).Range) > 0 Then Exit For
    Next i
    LastUsedRowIndex = i
End Function


Another interesting take
